# dimension and basis of a solution space based on the rank of a matrix and three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra and have been wrestling with the following question for hours. I have no teacher, and the answer book provides no key. Can anyone suggest a way to go about this?

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{ 4\times4}$, with rank $2$.
Suppose that the vectors
$u=(2,1,2,0),\, v=(1,-1,2,4),\, w=(1,0,2,-1)$
are solutions to the linear system $Ax=b$.

a. find the dimension of the solution space of the system $Ax=0$ and find its basis.

b. find the general solution to the system $Ax=b$.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is a matrix of rank $2$ which means that it has a $2$ dimensional kernel. Since $u,v,w$ have the same image, $u-v$ and $u-w$ are in the kernel. Since these two vectors are linearly independent, they span the kernel.

To get all solutions of $Ax=b$, you can take any solution and translate it with kernel elements, i.e every solution of the equation is of the form $u+c(u-v)+d(u-w)$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So the solution space is an affine linear space!

Comment: Yes, it is. This is in general true. For a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ in the image of $A$, the solutions of $Ax=b$ are always given by $u+N(A)$ where $u$ is a solution of the equation and $N(A)$ is the kernel of $A$.